# error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am new to angular. I tried to create a form with the template-driven approach. Then I got the following error when I compiled myapp. Can you please explain to me why this happens?

This is the error I got.
[image: This is the error I got.]

This is my app.module.ts file.
[image: This is my app.module.ts]

This is the form I created.
[image]

[image]